# Running WebDriver Tests on IE fails Randomly

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I had written some scripts using WebDriver which are able to run with firefox and Chrome perfectly. But running those scripts with IE , results in failure . I am facing a problem during the Window Handling Mechanisms. The following is the code for it.

```
public void switchingWindow() {
    HashSet<String> handles =(HashSet<String>) driver.getWindowHandles();;
    Iterator<String> whandles = handles.iterator();
    int h = 0;
    while(handles.size()<2) {
        handles = (HashSet<String>) driver.getWindowHandles();
        whandles = handles.iterator();
        System.out.println("No Of Windows : "+handles.size());
        h++;
        sleep(500);
        if (h >= 60)
            Assert.fail("Tracker PopUp not loaded successfully");
    }
    parentWindow = whandles.next();
    popUpWindow = whandles.next();
    driver.switchTo().window(popUpWindow);
    System.out.println("PopUp Window is handled");
}
```

Comment: The session expires suddenly. Mostly I am facing problem with the Window Handles. The script breaksdown unevenly. If a test case is passed one time, there is no gaurantee that it is passed on the next run.(All the test cases are independent of each other)

Answer (score 0):

Random failures that only occur in IE are often, in my experience, due to an element (in this case the window handler) not completely existing yet. IE seems to load elements in a different order/way (I don't know how) than Chrome and Firefox so I have often found I have to apply a waitUntil for IE where the other browsers I did not. However, this being window handlers I imagine this isn't the case, but if it is I also would nto be very surprised :P

Answer (score 0):

Launch a Google Chrome instance, and configure the IE Tab extension to open by default.. it emulates IE, but won't ever crash like Microsoft's products.